# imap_open in php file not working when run as a cron job in parallel plesk

Tags: php, cron, plesk, imap-open

I have a PHP script with the line:

```
$this->conn = imap_open('{'.$this->server.'/notls}', $this->user, $this->pass
```

It works when run in browser. 
However when run as a cron job on parallel plesk version 12 I get error:

> PHP Warning:  imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {localhost/notls} in
>   /var/www/vhosts/cvdatabase.management/httpdocs/send_email.php on line
>   115

I have browsed the internet and tried several fixes but so far nothing has worked. Any one know how to fix this?

Comment: Try to change localhost to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Because it run in CLI mode. In this mode $_SERVER variable not exist. Try run it like imap_open('{127.0.0.1/notls}'